# How to get cost fall between 2 dates in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, in one table i am saving cost based on different date batch and in another table i am saving the order date. What i need is to get cost from the table where order date falls between them.

```
create table #TempDateBatch
(
 Sku nvarchar(50),
 FromDate datetime,
 ToDate datetime,
 Cost decimal(12,2)
)

Insert into #TempDateBatch(Sku,FromDate,ToDate,Cost) values('Abc','2020-05-01','2020-05-31',12.3);
Insert into #TempDateBatch(Sku,FromDate,ToDate,Cost) values('Abc','2020-06-01','2020-06-05',10.3);

Create table #TempMain
(
 Sku nvarchar(50),
 ProductName nvarchar(50),
 OrderDate datetime
)
Insert into #TempMain(Sku,ProductName,OrderDate) values('Abc','Demo Prdouct','2020-05-10');
Insert into #TempMain(Sku,ProductName,OrderDate) values('Abc','Demo Prdouct','2020-06-03');
```

I need to get Sku and Order date from one table and i need to pick cost from another table on the date which that order falls.
**Example Something like this** -: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a `join`:

```
select m.*, db.cost
from #TempMain m left join
     #TempDateBatch db
     on m.sku = db.sku and
        m.orderdate between db.fromdate and db.todate
```